# How can I better page through folds in Vim?

Tags: vim

I usually have foldclose=all set so when I scroll through code, the folds automatically open and close. but sometimes I also like to quickly page through text using <C-d> and <C-u>. The problem is that this often jumps out of the fold I'm currently viewing and closes it before I have a chance to see the last bit. What I'm after is a way to page through the text and if I'm in an open fold, stop at the end of the fold if the next page would have taken me out of it. And if the cursor position is already at the last line of a fold, the next paging action will actually advance a page. I'm guessing this requires a vimscript function, so just want to see if anybody has done something similar.

Comment: If the cursor is on the last line of an open fold, do you want to advance a page while leaving the fold open? Does the `scrolloff` option help you? It lets you see a few lines below the lowest cursor position, so it may help you out. I have `scrolloff=5` and it's helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with this:

```
function! FoldawareCD()
  let there = line('.') + &scroll
  let nextl = line('.') + 1 
  if foldlevel('.') > 0 && foldclosed('.') == -1 && (foldclosed(there) != -1 || foldlevel(there) == 0) && (foldclosed(nextl) == -1 && foldlevel(nextl) > 0)
        call feedkeys("]z")
  else      
        call feedkeys("^D")
  endif     
endfunction


noremap <F1> :call FoldawareCD()<CR>
```

#### `If` exaplanation

- `foldlevel('.') > 0 && foldclosed('.') == -1`

  true when we are in an open fold
- `(foldclosed(there) != -1 || foldlevel(there) == 0)`

  true when <kbd>^D</kbd> would land on a closed fold or on a non-fold
- `(foldclosed(nextl) == -1 && foldlevel(nextl) > 0)`

  true when the next line is in our fold (so we are *not* on the last line of our open fold)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to the following mapping

```
nnoremap <C-D> Lz.
nnoremap <C-U> Hz.
```

That move the cursor to the first/last visible line and the scroll so it become the middle line.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding this to your .vimrc file.  I'm not sure it does exactly what your asking for, but its the best I've found.

```
set foldmethod=syntax   "fold based on indent
set foldnestmax=10      "deepest fold is 10 levels
set nofoldenable        "dont fold by default
set foldlevel=1         "this is just what i use
```

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't even come close.